# wget connection reset by peer

Tags: tcp, connection, udp, wget

I try to access www.indeed.com from our web server by using wget but it raises "Connection reset by peer" error.

```
wget www.indeed.com

--2013-02-05 03:03:12--  (try: 3)  http://www.indeed.com/
Connecting to www.indeed.com|208.43.224.140|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

It was working before cause I'm using their API for a while but now I'm not even reach their public website.

What could it be the problem? Could Indeed add to their blacklist the server's IP or is this related with my firewall etc.?

Is there a way to debug/trace where the problem is?

Comment: Try `curl -i www.indeed.com | less`. It works for me.

Comment: It works from my local too. Only occurs this in my webserver

Comment: maybe they banned you?

Comment: Yea I think so as I mentioned. However I couldn't get any response from them. It's also very unusual to banned the IP without any notification. So is there anyway to verify that our webserver's IP banned?

Comment: Scan them: `nmap -sV -T4 -F indeed.com`

Answer (score 5):

You should use with user-agent like following sample

```
wget "http://www.indeed.com/" --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"
```