# wget connection reset by peer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use the command below to download all mp4 videos from that site:

```
wget -r -A.mp4 http://ia600300.us.archive.org/18/items/MIT6.262S11/
```

However, it reports "Read error, Connection reset by peer", 
I have found threads like [wget connection reset by peer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698513/wget-connection-reset-by-peer), but it's not solved by using wget.
So is there any way to download those videos from that site with wget command?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the page and has a robot.txt file, so you need to add `-e robots=off`

Use this to download all mp4 files:

```
wget -A mp4 -r -e robots=off http://ia600300.us.archive.org/18/items/MIT6.262S11/
```

Comment: But I didn't find that file, where did you find robots.txt? And why should I add -e robots=off

Comment: If you execute your command it will donwload a `robots.txt` file, so you need to tell your wget command to ignore robots, so this is what you need to add `-e robots=off`, and your filter for `mp4` files was incorrect